# hadoop putting data on master not relecting on all clusters

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have set up a hadoop cluster of 3 nodes for testing. Everything works fine, but when i upload the file into master node using the following command

**./bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal localfolderName hdfsfolderName**

The files are reflected only in data node of master node.

I thought that hadoop will split the input files and spread the chunks across all the slave nodes.

I want to know if i am missing any configuration, or its how the hadoop behaves??

Comment: You mean the entire file sits just on 1 machine?How are you verifying that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I verified it by checking the number of blocks in each node on web page. Other two nodes have 0 blocks and the 1 machine has around 68 blocks.

Comment: Are other DNs up and running properly?Run the balancer once and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: DNS are up and running, I can even run a Map/Reduce jobs on the cluster. I saw that when the disk capacity of the first node got exhausted it started moving the data to the second node.  This makes me feel that there is some configurations i am missing. Is there a strategy of how hadoop shards its data??